# Kinectic JS - How to get the scaled height of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I'm trying to get the scaled height/width of element in KinecticJS, but getHeight()/getWidth() only returns the original height and width, not the scaled one. Is there a function I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
//Get scale...
var scale = target.getScale().x;
var height = target.getHeight(); var width = target.getWidth();

//Get scaled height by multiplying the scale by the width/height
var scaleWidth = scale*width; var scaleHeight = scale*height;
```